# Is there any way to optimize this SQL Server query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query which takes 2 minutes to execute even the time period is not that long:

```
SELECT MTI.DeptID,
       ShortEmployees.EmpID,
       ShortEmployees.EmpName1 AS EmpName,
       Sum(CASE
             WHEN (BSR.BSTID = 3
                   AND bli.state IN (12, 13, 14)) THEN -1 * ((BLD.Qty / dbo.Getunitval(BLD.UnitID, BLD.MTID)) * BLD.Price - ((BLD.Qty / dbo.Getunitval(BLD.UnitID, BLD.MTID)) * BLD.Price * BLD.discount * 0.01))
             ELSE ((BLD.Qty / dbo.Getunitval(BLD.UnitID, BLD.MTID)) * BLD.Price - ((BLD.Qty / dbo.Getunitval(BLD.UnitID, BLD.MTID)) * BLD.Price * BLD.discount * 0.01))
           END) AS Total
FROM   BLD
       INNER JOIN BLI
         ON BLD.BLNo = BLI.BLNo
       INNER JOIN BSR
         ON BLI.BLID = BSR.BLID
       INNER JOIN ShortEmployees
         ON BLI.EmpID = ShortEmployees.EmpID
       INNER JOIN MTI
         ON BLD.MTID = MTI.MTID
WHERE  (MTI.DeptID = 'B')
       AND (BLI.BLDate > Cast('2013-01-01 00:00:00' AS DATETIME))
       AND (BLI.BLDate < Cast('2013-01-14 23:59:59' AS DATETIME))
       AND ((BSR.BSTID = 2
             AND bli.state IN (2, 6, 8, 9,
                               10, 12, 18))
             OR (BSR.BSTID = 3
                 AND bli.state IN (12, 13, 14)))
GROUP  BY ShortEmployees.EmpName1,
          ShortEmployees.EmpID,
          MTI.DeptID
ORDER  BY Total DESC
```

How I can optimize it?

MTI: Items information table.

BLI: Bills table.

BLD: Bill details table.

ShortEmployees: Salesmen table.

Comment: First step would be to break the query in better formatted lines so people can even begin trying to optimize it

Comment: What indexes do you have on these tables?

Comment: Yes, you can optimize `dbo.Getunitval` ;)

Comment: @Mhdali He's right though, most people will move on if you don't put the minimum of effort in. Next time, try running your query through this online formatter I use: http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm

Comment: I agree with @TimSchmelter - judging by the name, it sounds like a function which could be turned into a join.

Comment: dbo.Getunitval is a very simple function, it returns a value of unit.

Comment: @Mhdali How? Does it do a calculation, or does it go look the value up in a table?

Comment: @Bridge look it up in MTI, because of bad MTI table design, previous developer stored the units values as UnitID1,UnitVal1,UnitID2, UnitVal2...etc columns, so I wrote this function to get the UnitVal by passing the MTID and UnitID

Comment: @Mhdali Sounds like you could turn that into a pivot table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I ended up converting that query into whole stored procedure and the difference is huge! now it takes 2 seconds only :), thanks everybody specially the hater spanky ;)

Answer (score 1):

Move conditions into the JOKN ON clauses where they can be applied as the join is made, rather than filtering after all joins have been made:

```
SELECT MTI.DeptID,
       ShortEmployees.EmpID,
       ShortEmployees.EmpName1 AS EmpName,
       Sum(CASE
             WHEN (BSR.BSTID = 3
                   AND bli.state IN (12, 13, 14)) THEN -1 * ((BLD.Qty / dbo.Getunitval(BLD.UnitID, BLD.MTID)) * BLD.Price - ((BLD.Qty / dbo.Getunitval(BLD.UnitID, BLD.MTID)) * BLD.Price * BLD.discount * 0.01))
             ELSE ((BLD.Qty / dbo.Getunitval(BLD.UnitID, BLD.MTID)) * BLD.Price - ((BLD.Qty / dbo.Getunitval(BLD.UnitID, BLD.MTID)) * BLD.Price * BLD.discount * 0.01))
           END) AS Total
FROM BLD
JOIN BLI ON BLD.BLNo = BLI.BLNo
    AND BLI.BLDate BETWEEN Cast('2013-01-01 00:00:00' AS DATETIME)
       AND Cast('2013-01-14 23:59:59' AS DATETIME)
JOIN BSR ON BLI.BLID = BSR.BLID
    AND ((BSR.BSTID = 2
             AND bli.state IN (2, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 18)
        OR (BSR.BSTID = 3
             AND bli.state IN (12, 13, 14))
JOIN ShortEmployees ON BLI.EmpID = ShortEmployees.EmpID
JOIN MTI ON BLD.MTID = MTI.MTID
    AND MTI.DeptID = 'B'
GROUP BY ShortEmployees.EmpName1,
    ShortEmployees.EmpID,
    MTI.DeptID
ORDER BY Total DESC
```

Note that I changed the date range check to a BETWEEN, because your query excluded the first and last seconds of the period.

I also removed unnecessary brackets and indentation

Comment: Previously it was taking 1:53 and now it takes 1:55 :D no big difference.

Answer (score 0):

For additional optimization, move the Cast('XXXXX' AS DATETIME) in variables :

```
DECLARE @dmin DATETIME= Cast('2013-01-01 00:00:00' AS DATETIME);
DECLARE @dmax DATETIME= Cast('2013-01-14 23:59:59' AS DATETIME);
SELECT [blah]
FROM   [blahblah]
WHERE  (MTI.DeptID = 'B')
       AND (BLI.BLDate BETWEEN @dmin AND @dmax)
etc
```